# How to define main class location for a plugin system

Tags: java, annotations, find, classpath

So let's say I have a classpath `dummy.class.path.Plugin`
and now I need to get that path and find it with `Class.forName()`

Note: The main class is annotated with annotation `@Plugin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended creating a scanner system using http://asm.ow2.org/ for this and just scanning thru classes using `URLClassLoader`